# JSON output incorrect - Python Project

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I have to develop a program which stores in a json file a list , which must be readable in order to modify one single element, delete one, add one etc...
The json file content never is right, I don't understand how it changes when I add a element, so something must be wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

```
import json



class ABC:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__list = []


        try:
            file=open(self.__filename,"r")
            self.__lista.append(json.load(file))
            print(self.__lista)
        except:
            file=open(self.__filename, "w")
            file.close()
            file = open(self.__filename, "r")


    def add(self, c):
        print(self.__lista)
        self.__lista.append(str(c))
        #print(self.__lista)



    def write_to_json_file(self):
        with open(self.__filename, '+a') as json_file:
            json.dump(self.__lista, json_file, indent=2)
            json_file.write(',')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open file with the option `+a` for append. And the `__lista = dict()`

```
class Carta:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__lista = dict()

def add(self, c):
    self.__lista.update(c.__dict__)
    print(self.__lista)
    #print(self.__lista)



def write_to_json_file(self, c):
    with open(self.__filename, 'a') as json_file:
        json.dump(self.__lista, json_file, indent=2)
        json_file.write(',')
```

See `json` function and `open` function in the python doc.

Comment: So this portion of code should go as  'write_to_json_funcion' ? How will I be able to append something in the add funcion if ' __lista' is a dictionary?

Comment: In the function `write_to_json_file(self)` open the file with +a to be able to append in file. `dict()` type is to simply the json conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much, please take a look at the updated code and at the json file I have added to the post

Comment: The output is now what you expect?

Comment: No, I want to be able to add new cocktails. Also, the json code is not formatted right.

Comment: I edited and changed your add function. Changed your filename as a `dict()`. Must works as you want

Comment: I now have the right output if I add one element and save right afterwards, but if I want to add more than one before saving I can't. The __lista which should contain all cocktails in order to make me edit them does contain only the last one, I suppose